# Please advise: two Unexpected_Kernel_Mode_Trap BSODs right after refreshing Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod, crash

I've been plagued by BSODs for months now, and just when I think I've solved the cause of one error type, I start getting them of a totally different error type, so today I bit the bullet and refreshed my Windows install. As I began the arduous task of reinstalling my most important programs, I was almost immediately hit with an Unexpected_Kernel_Mode_Trap. I restarted, at not long after I got another.

I've heard that type of BSOD error can sometimes be caused by bad RAM, but I've run memtest86 and it turned up clean. Anyone have a clue what's going on?

EDIT: I forgot Windows doesn't like it when you try to upload a file straight from C:\Windows\Minidump. Here they are now. [First](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pZ6NHfMU2F7F_9fBlnk5LxkwYjN0_T0x) crash, [second](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SGBvBHpLF5-uskeDyuSSODA_Ks0a7cVT) crash, and I just noticed a Driver_State_Power_Failure BSOD at 2 am last night, so [here's that](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IWn2wB_xlqdElf153HHPX6zsMj_IiPdZ) too.

Answer (score 0):

Usually
[DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x9f--driver-power-state-failure)
denotes a driver failure, but an examination of the stack at the time of the
crash shows no active driver.

The
[UNEXPECTED_KERNEL_MODE_TRAP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x7f--unexpected-kernel-mode-trap)
crash has also no driver on the stack.

The latest error is defined as:

> This bug check indicates that the Intel CPU generated a trap and the kernel failed to catch this trap.

Its error sub-code, `0x00000008`, only adds the unhelpful description:

> Double Fault, indicates that an exception occurs during a call to the handler for a prior exception.

In conclusion, you have exceptions chasing exceptions too fast for Windows
to handle.

I think you have developed some hardware problems.
For a start, I suggest running
[Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/)
to test your memory. Let it run for 6-8 passes, which will take hours.
If you have errors, let us know and add the test logfile to your post.

Comment: Damn, I was afraid of that. Thanks for doing that analysis though. I've run memtest86+ with no errors (but I think it defaulted to 4 passes). I'm replacing half my RAM today anyway, so I'll run memtest86+ overnight, figure out how to make it do 8 passes to be safe, and hopefully post the results tomorrow morning.